# C# convert datetimeoffset to string with milliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

The default toString() method in datetimeoffset converts the time into string format but loses the milliseconds. Is there anyway to preserve it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ToString()` takes a format argument.  There are existing string format codes that will print milliseconds - take a look at the [list here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

For example the format code "o" will print a full time string with milliseconds, or you can create your own format string to match your needs and use the "ffff" specifier to add milliseconds where appropriate.

```
myDateTime.ToString("o")
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to use "ffff" in the string format to get miliseconds, like:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
 string strDate = String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm.ss:ffff}", date);
```

Mitja

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the f character in your format string.

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("ddMMyyy-HH:mm:ss")
```

Gives "23032011-16:58:36"

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("ddMMyyy:HHmmssffff")
```

Gives "23032011-16:59:088562"

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346136.aspx) of `DateTimeOffset` this behaves in most ways similar to `ToString` of the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) class. This means that you can for example use the standard format string `o` which shows the milliseconds, or you can use whatever [custom format pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) you want.

So you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(dto.ToString("o"));
```